# generate unique id in nested document - Pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

generate unique id in nested document - Pymongo

my database looks like this...

```
{
  "_id":"5ea661d6213894a6082af6d1",

  "blog_id":"blog_one",

  "comments":  [
          {
            "user_id":"1",
            "comment":"comment for blog one this is good"
          },
          {
            "user_id":"2",
            "comment":"other for blog one"
          },
  ]
}
```

I want to add unique id in each and every comment,

I want it to output like this,

```
{
  "_id":"5ea661d6213894a6082af6d1",

  "blog_id":"blog_one",

  "comments": [
           {
            "id" : "something"     (auto generate unique),
            "user_id":"1",
            "comment":"comment for blog one this is good"
           },
           {
            "id" : "something"    (auto generate unique),
            "user_id":"2",
            "comment":"other for blog one"
           },
     ]
}
```

I'm using PyMongo, is there a way to update this kind of document?

it's possible or not?

Answer (score 2):

This update will add an unique id value to each of the `comments` array with nested documents. The `id` value is calculated based upon the present time as milliseconds. This value is incremented for each array element to get the new `id` value for the nested documents of the array.

The code runs with MongoDB version 4.2 and PyMongo 3.10.

```
pipeline = [
  { 
      "$set": {
         "comments": { 
             "$map": {
                 "input": { "$range": [ 0, { "$size": "$comments" } ] },
                 "in": {
                     "$mergeObjects": [ 
                         { "id": { "$add": [ { "$toLong" : datetime.datetime.now() }, "$$this" ] } },
                         { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$comments", "$$this" ] }
                     ]
                 }
             }
         }
      }
  }
]

collection.update_one( { }, pipeline )
```

The updated document:

```
{
        "_id" : "5ea661d6213894a6082af6d1",
        "blog_id" : "blog_one",
        "comments" : [
                {
                        "id" : NumberLong("1588179349566"),
                        "user_id" : "1",
                        "comment" : "comment for blog one this is good"
                },
                {
                        "id" : NumberLong("1588179349567"),
                        "user_id" : "2",
                        "comment" : "other for blog one"
                }
        ]
}
```

---

[ EDIT ADD ]

The following works from `mongo` shell. It adds unique id for the `comments` array's nested documents - unique across the documents.

```
db.collection.aggregate( [
  { 
      "$unwind": "$comments" },
  { 
      "$group": { 
          "_id": null, 
          "count": { "$sum": 1 }, 
          "docs": { "$push": "$$ROOT"  },
          "now": { $first: "$$NOW" }
      } 
  },
  { 
      "$addFields": {
          "docs": { 
              "$map": {
                   "input": { "$range": [ 0, "$count" ] },
                   "in": {
                       "$mergeObjects": [ 
                           { "comments_id": { "$add": [ { "$toLong" : "$now" }, "$$this" ] } },
                           { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$docs", "$$this" ] }
                     ]
                 }
             }
         }
      }
  },
  { 
      "$unwind": "$docs" 
  },
  { 
      "$addFields": { 
          "docs.comments.comments_id": "$docs.comments_id" 
      } 
  },
  { 
      "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$docs" } 
  },
  { 
      "$group": { 
          "_id": { "_id": "$_id", "blog_id": "$blog_id" }, 
          "comments": { "$push": "$comments" } 
      } 
  },
  { 
      $project: { 
          "_id": 0, 
          "_id": "$_id._id", 
          "blog_id": "$_id.blog_id", 
          "comments": 1 
      } 
  }
] ).forEach(doc => db.blogs.updateOne( { _id: doc._id }, { $set: { comments: doc.comments } } ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ObjectId constructor](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/bson/objectid.html) to create the ids and place them in your nested documents.

Comment: This will not work, the `ObjectId` constructor will put the same value in all the array elements. It only generates 1 ObjectId (same results in pymongo and the shell)

Comment: Take the generated ID and manually place it wherever you like.